# How to add/modify new variable values in es_ES.po file using WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use my own defined variables

1-  I used es_ES.po
2-  #: wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/tmp_login_step1.php:16
        msgid "Register a new account"
        msgstr "Registrar una cuenta nueva"

3-  On line 16

But it is not translating it is just showin __e(“Register a new account”)

As it is Register a new account

In fact if I use some other __e(“sweetheart”) from the es_ES.po file which is already filled, it worked but why don’t my own defined variables are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explanation should help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

You need to generate the MO (Machine Object) file with a translation tool.